# Grails with EJB 3.0 Session bean

Tags: grails, ejb-3.0

I am wondering if any one has ever tried running grails with ejb stateful session beans ?
Any relevant link or sample code will help me a lot to take decision on weather to got with grails in the web tier or stick with tried and tested JSF+Spring MVC

Thanks

Comment: Here is [a sample app](https://github.com/milankinen/grails-remote-ejb-example) using Stateless Session beans (EJB 3). I suppose working on stateful session beans will not be a huge difference from this implementation.